# How would I write a 16-bit integer to multiple bytes in Golang?

Tags: encoding, binary, go

Let's say I have the 16 bit integer 259 (0000000100000011 in binary) and I want to write it to a byte stream in Go. A byte is only 8 bits, so how can I split the integer across multiple bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`binary.Write`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/) method of the encoding/binary package.

```
buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
err := binary.Write(buf, binary.BigEndian, uint16(259))
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("binary.Write failed:", err)
}

// This should be two bytes with your encoded integer.
fmt.Println(buf.Bytes())
```